How to set scope in Auth provider for extending token expiry on JIRA server?
While setting up named credentials or Auth provider using OAuth2 for connecting to Jira on premise, The incoming link in JIRA is configured correctly and I am able to pull data but the session expires or access token expires after sometime (7200ms as per documentation). How can I set the refresh token url or extend this expiry token using scope parameter.

This is a known limitation in Jira on premise. For Jira cloud, it works fine with the scope. Refer known issues in jira server section.
